# How to cut a 1 5/8 hole in plexiglass with a hole saw and not break the plexi

Tags: drill, plastic

I'm making a router base plate to accommodate a larger round over bit. I need to cut a large hole through the plexi for bit clearance and I don't want to break or crack the plexiglass.

Comment: Think I would try reverse rotation and grind the plexi instead of having the teeth cut chips out of it.  Only made straight cuts in plexi with a diamond saw blade.

Comment: Plexiglass is really brittle, yes it can be cut with a hole saw, I have had the best luck with a sandwich wood plexiglass wood held together with clamps, after pilot bit is through start dribbling water in the hole, once wood is cut through add more water in the large hole high speed not much force and keep wet, I made a great 1/2’ base for a router and the first carbide I had that let loose shattered all my hard work. I then went to polycarbonate cashier to cut and it won’t fracture like plexiglass, the first polycarbonate base I made 5-6 years ago is still in use. My plexiglass lasted 1 day.

Comment: heating it first will make it less brittle. enough heat will melt it at which point it can't really shatter. You don't need to go that far, but almost too hot to touch would be beneficial.

Comment: I made a router base using a forstner bit in a drill press to cut the hole in plexiglass. The speed was fairly low and it came out fine other than having to sand down the edge

Answer (score 1):

If the hole saw is diamond, then it should have no problem cutting through the plexiglass and as long as the plexiglass is against a flat surface where the stress is evenly distributed you should have no problems. As others have mentioned, you could heat the plexiglass to help ensure it doesn't crack.

In some cases, you may need/want to clamp the plexiglass down to something sturdy (a workbench, anything heavier than 10 pounds, etc.) and that would make it all that more stable. Additionally, ensure you go a slower pace to help prevent isolated heat buildup. Others have also mentioned this in the comments, just wanted to reiterate that.